# summarise with mean, median, range and quants in R

Tags: r, mean, median, quantile, summarize

I am currently working with the palmer penguins data set in R and want to summarise data that combines means, median, range and quants, grouping by sex.

My current solution has the quant data split from the summary data. Is there a way to do this in one go. If not how do I combine the data sets. The group quant is currently in long format, and I am not sure how to combine them.

```
group_summary <- penguins %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarize(mean = mean(bill_length_mm, 
na.rm = TRUE), meadian = median(bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE), range = 
max(bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE) - min(bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE))

group_quant <- penguins %>% group_by(sex) %>% summarize(quantile(bill_length_mm, 
probs =seq(.1, 1, by = .1), na.rm =TRUE, .groups = 'drop'))
```

I had the following solution but it drops the NA values from Sex and I am not sure why.

```
group_summary <- do.call(data.frame,aggregate(bill_length_mm ~ sex, penguins, 
function(x) c(mean = mean(x, na.rm = TRUE), median = median(x, na.rm = TRUE), range = 
max(x, na.rm = TRUE) - min(x, na.rm = TRUE), quantile(x, probs = seq(.1, 1, by = .1), 
na.rm = TRUE, .groups = 'drop'))))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may save the quantiles in a list and then use `unnest_wider` to create new columns from them. To calculate `range` I used `diff(range(...))` instead of `max(...) - min(...)`. Both of them are fine but I included it to show an alternative.

```
library(palmerpenguins)
library(dplyr)
library(tidyr)

penguins %>% 
  group_by(sex) %>% 
  summarize(mean = mean(bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE), 
            median = median(bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE), 
            range = diff(range(bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE)), 
            quantile = list(quantile(bill_length_mm, probs = seq(.1, 1, by = .1), na.rm = TRUE))) %>%
  unnest_wider(quantile)

#   sex     mean median range `10%` `20%` `30%` `40%` `50%` `60%` `70%` `80%` `90%` `100%`
#  <fct>  <dbl>  <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl> <dbl>  <dbl>
#1 female  42.1   42.8  25.9  35.8  36.7  38.2  40    42.8  45.1  45.7  46.5  47.5   58  
#2 male    45.9   46.8  25    38.8  40.5  41.3  43.2  46.8  49.0  50.0  50.8  51.9   59.6
#3 NA      41.3   42    13.2  36.8  37.7  37.8  38.6  42    44    44.5  45.2  46.4   47.3
```

Comment: Awesome, thanks for the response. Is it possible to add an additional observation that is all of them combined. I can do this separately and add it but just curious for my own knowledge if you can do it at the same time as the others. Basically another row called "all" as it relates to the 2 sexes + NA.

Comment: Do you want the sum of all the observations in a new row ? You can add `janitor::adorn_totals` to the pipe above.

Comment: not the sum, but rather the mean, media, quants etc without the group_by(sex). Given the data is previously grouped I would assume we can't then have a row called "all". This row would use all values to find the means of the entire bill_length_mm without consideration for sex. @Ronak

Comment: I can get the summary with: `all_summary <- data.frame( t(c(sex="all", 
                               mean = mean(penguins$bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE), 
                               median = median(penguins$bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE), 
                               range = diff(range(penguins$bill_length_mm, na.rm = TRUE)), 
                               quantile(penguins$bill_length_mm, probs = seq(.1, 1, by = .1), na.rm = TRUE))))`

and then rbind it with the original frame. Which seems correct but wondering if you can somehow do this without creating the second variable.